# Show the latest handset and 2nd last handset used by customer in Oracle SQL. Requirement attached in image

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can anyone help to answer the question attached in image

Q1: Print Customer name and latest handset

Q2: Customer name with 2nd last handset

[Requirements are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdLU3.png)

Thanks

Comment: This is obviously homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because you are supposed to come here with a concrete problem you are stuck with. Instead you show us the task you have been given and asks us to do the work for you. Next time do some work yourself, show us how far you've got and what problems you are facing. Also please don't link to images. Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20often%20blocked%20by,t%20useful%20to%20future%20readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions. This gives you the latest handset:

```
select c.*, d.handset
from customer c
inner join (
    select d.*, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by start_date desc) rn
    from device d
) d on d.customer_id = c.id
where d.rn = 1
```

You can change the `where` clause to `rn = 2` if you want the second last handset.